# Need to print out details of the books if isOnLoan is false? Using setters getters

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, getter-setter

```
Boolean status = false; 
for (int i = 0; i<SomeArray.length; i++)   { 
    if(status == SomeArray[i].getisOnLoan()) { 
        System.out.print("\n" + SomeArray[i].toString());  
    }
}
```

I need to print out all the objects of array where isOnLoan is = to false but I have tried number of times and I keep getting null pointer exception etc. I even used status variable to compare the values to see if it was false but no one it is working

Comment: Has `SomeArray` and it's elements been initialized.  Also, it's standard practice for variables to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Why `status` is `Boolean` and not `boolean`?

Comment: Check if the array is initialized and also paste the stack trace here so that people can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two potential causes of `NullPointerException` in your code snippet:

- `someArray` is `null`
- some cells from `someArray` are `null`.

Assuming `someArray` is not `null`, here's a solution (and cleaner):

```
for (int i = 0; i<someArray.length; i++) 
        if(someArray[i] != null && !someArray[i].isOnLoan())  //notice the check for nullity since your current cell could be null
                 System.out.println(someArray[i]);
```

And please follow the Java naming convention.

Comment: Sorry Its my first time asking a question and I dont want to give away the code due to reasons.

Comment: You shouldn't provide your real code, just a conceptual sample of your issue.